# JQuery CDN not working, and local JS script not seen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand this for the life of me. I normally work with Python, but am trying to dabble a bit in web development with JQuery. I've used the CDN from google, and have done everything from putting the script below the footer (A site I found said that was the best spot), to moving it up into the header (every other site I've been to since says that is the best spot), and nothing works.

From the error in the inspection tools 'Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:63342/HTML/Omnifood/resources/javascript/script.js”.' It suggests to me that it can't even find the .js file I created to hold my code, but it is there, defined. (See screenshots attached)

Any help getting this sorted out would be appreciated.

Screenshot of HTML and file structure, as well as error in inspection tool:
[image]

[image]

Edit: The issue has been resolved in so far as the folder has been moved to the correct location (/resources/javascript/script.js), I even went in and added `type="text/javascript"` to all the script files just in case. Now when attempting to run script with following JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('h1').click(function() {
       $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000')
   })
});
```

I get the following errors in inspection tool:

[image]

Comment: Your server is not configured properly, you've to add .js to the MIME types.

Comment: I agree with @Teemu. Download the cdns and keep in your resources and then use 'static' keyword to access it

Comment: BTW. To me it looks like script.js is saved in vendors/javascript directory. But my first comment still stands, the server is responding with an error page (which is .html), as it should respond with status 404 and empty body.

Comment: have you tried to add type='text/javascript' to the cdn script source ? since i have seen that the script sources are considered for a strange reason that are of type text/html

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with CDN resources. You're just using the wrong path to load your `script.js` file

Comment: Yes, it was under the wrong folder. Moved it to the correct folder and now it sees the script, but offers 'ReferenceError: module is not defined' and 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question regarding the module not found issue

Comment: If you're new to js, do you know *why* you've included `/npm/respond@0.9.0/main.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is wrong http://localhost:63342/HTML/Omnifood/resources/javascript/script.js

your script.js is at

http://localhost:63342/HTML/Omnifood/vendors/javascript/script.js

Comment: Yes, it was under the wrong folder. Moved it to the correct folder and now it sees the script, but offers 'ReferenceError: module is not defined' and 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Comment: Can you give us more details, it is hard to debug with only this information.

Comment: Where is this main.js I don't see it on the picture, also try if the CDN is working properly by going to the URL, it should load.

Comment: The CDN works properly, and I was confused on the main.js as well. I don't have a 'main.js' file. All the scripts I am using are found in the picture above. If it helps. I have my entire project on a code pen as well found here: https://codepen.io/RuleofThree/pen/wvMdmyb

Comment: For the pen you should load JQuery from Pen Settings and remove the cdn and it works fine.

Comment: It must be an issue with the program I am using then. Thanks.